# How do I stop URL.Action from including parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url.action

In my main navigation I have a link to:

`Url.Action("Items", "FAQ");`

The link works fine and I get to `~/Item/FAQ`

However, I have links which contain parameters, so:

`~/Items/FAQ/Question-1`

This all works fine, however, when I'm viewing Question-1 (which is a View, the link in the main navigation changes to:

`~/Items/FAQ/Question-1`

How do I keep the Url in the navigation to stay at `~/Items/FAQ`

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Url.Action("Items", "FAQ", new { WhateverYourRouteParameterIsCalled = "" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer but couldn't get it to work. In the end, I used a (comparatively) low tech solution:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Items/FAQ")">Nav Target Text</a>
```

This ignores any id values set by visiting that same page.