# ASP.Net Mvc 3 Url.Action method uses parameter values from previous request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-routing

When Urls are autogenerated using the `Url.Action` helper, if a page contains a line similar to

> @Url.Action("Edit","Student")

is expected to generate a url like `domain/student/edit` and its working as expected.
But if the requested url contains some parameters, like `domain/student/edit/210`, the above code uses these parameters from the previous request and generates something similar even though I've not provided any such parameter to the `Action` method.

In short, if the requested url contains any parameters, any auto generated links of the page (served for that request) will include those parameters as well no matter if I specify them or not in the `Url.Action` method.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Weird, can't seem to reproduce the problem:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and inside `Index.cshtml`:

```
@Url.Action("About", "Home")
```

Now when I request `/home/index/123` the url helper generates `/home/about` as expected. No ghost parameters. So how does your scenario differs?

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have clarified your scenario it seems that you have the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and inside `Index.cshtml` you are trying to use:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home")
```

If you request `/home/index/123` this generates `/home/index/123` instead of the expected `/home/index` (or simply `/` taken into account default values).

This behavior is by design. If you want to change it you will have to write your own helper which ignores the current route data. Here's how it might look:

```
@UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
    "Default", 
    "index", 
    "home", 
    null, 
    Url.RouteCollection, 
    // That's the important part and it is where we kill the current RouteData
    new RequestContext(Html.ViewContext.HttpContext, new RouteData()), 
    false
)
```

This will generate the proper url you were expecting. Of course this is ugly. I would recommend you encapsulating it into a reusable helper.

Comment: Not that way, try to generate the link for the same page without parameters, but request the page with parameters. So in your case, try to generate link for index page itself.

Comment: @Threecoins, ahhh OK, got it. That's by design.

Comment: oh, so I cant generate a link without parameters within the same page if the request has got parameters??

Comment: @Threecoins, you can but you will have to write your own helper. See my update for an alternative.

Comment: Thank you. better than nothing, will make it an extension to the `HtmlHelper`, But why is it like this by design? Any particular advantage or historical reasons for that?

Comment: this is the extension i made to the UrlHelper    public static string GenerateUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName)
        {

            var urlHelperWithNewContext = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext, new RouteData()), urlHelper.RouteCollection);
            return urlHelperWithNewContext.Action(actionName, controllerName);
        }

Answer (score 20):

Use Darin's answer from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819722/590719).

```
@Url.Action("Edit","Student", new { ID = "" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionLink overload that uses parameters and supply null

Comment: seems like I can't assign null to anonymous property types.

Comment: @Mathew Cast `null` to `dynamic` to assign it to anonymous property types. But like Darin says, yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ken I ended up assigning "/". It  is a hack, but works for simple urls.

Answer (score 0):

You could register custom route for this action for example:

```
routes.MapRoute("Domain_EditStudentDefault",
            "student/edit",
            new { 
                controller = MVC.Student.Name, 
                action = MVC.Student.ActionNames.Edit,
                ID = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            new object(),
            new[] { "MySolution.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

you then could use `url.RouteUrl("Domain_EditStudentDefault")` url RouteUrl helper override with only `routeName` parameter which generates url without parameters.